# Post request to create node in drupal 6 from external site does not create node but returns HTTP 200 ok status

Tags: 6, services

I have been able to configure a rest Rest server from my Drupal 6 site using services 3.0 module.

I am able to make a get request successfully with an http response code 200 OK with the data related to the node id in json format. Following image shows this

[image: response when making get request from Rest client on Mozill Firefox]

But when I make a post request to create a new node using the same url and method as post, the response code is http 200 OK, but the new node is not actually created in Drupal 6. Following image shows this.
 [image: response when making post request from Rest client on Mozill Firefox]

Can someone correct my methodology please. Is there something wrong with my post request? I am using services 3 on a Drupal 6 website. I need to make such a post call from an external site to drupal 6.

And below is the image showing response text for this post call:
[image]

Comment: Did you login for creating new node?

Comment: @StoneVo if he didn't, he should get either 5xx error, or better 401, 403 or maybe 406. Definitely not 200. So if it's login problem, it's a plain bug.

Comment: @Molot you're right. It will be return 401 Unauthorized message. user1153986: can you show the response text (not response header)

Comment: @Mołot I have attached the response text also to the question.

Comment: OK, looks like node was not created. So, what's in watchdog for that moment? And in server's error log? @StoneVo response text says anything more to you?

Comment: watchdog is empty, the server php-log file shows last error as
 [07-Jun-2013 07:02:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot unset string offsets in /srv/bindings/3df751b4e1e44f53a9ade99178040c66/code/sites/all/modules/cck/includes/content.node_form.inc on line 60

Comment: @Mołot Could you find some clue fromt hat error?

Comment: Yes, it is a known bug https://drupal.org/node/583852

Comment: But that doesn't provide a solution to this problem .

Comment: @user1153986 Yes it does...have you tried the recommendations and confirmed they don't solve the issue? If so, you need to carry on the discussion on Drupal.org - we don't deal with bug reports here I'm afraid

Comment: Since there is a module that is causing a fatal error, I am closing this question as off-topic. Modules should not raise any fatal error; if that happens, report a bug in the queue of the module causing it. The node is not successfully created because that fatal error.

Comment: @[kiamlaluno](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno)The issue in the given url is quiet old and its fix must have been applied into the cck module by now. I doubt this as the bug

Comment: @user1153986 Fixedfield's last stable release was in 2009 - four years ago! And it's maintenance status is Unknown. Age is not an argument here. And it's pretty hard to create new, different bug with the same error message, on the same line in the same file. Maybe you are using similar module passing equally bad data to CCK, but that's still just a bug.

Comment: @Mołot I am afraid that you are wrong as its not a bug. I tried using cck module on another drupal 6 and it completely works. Can we now discuss this logically if thats a proof enough ?